# Reynolds number with hyper-viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, viscosity

Is it possible to evaluate a [Reynolds number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number) when viscosity operator is substituted by hyper-viscosity operator at the power H (Laplacien to the power H) in the incompressible [Navier-Stokes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) equations ?

Comment: Have you tried non-dimensionalizing the equations to see what the equivalent parameter, if any, would be?

Comment: @tpg2114 no, I should have, thanks for your comment.

Comment: No problem. Teach a man to fish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the equation:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u_i + u_j \partial_j u_i=-\partial_i p+ \nu_{hyper} \Delta^H u_i
\end{equation}
with $u$ the velocity in $m.s^{-1}$ and is characteristic order $U$, $p$ the pressure in $m^{2}.s^{-2}$, $\nu$ the hyper-viscosity in $m^{2H}.s^{-1}$. The characteristic length scale is note $L$ in $m$.

Following the non-dimensionalizing, the number Reynolds like is:
\begin{equation}
Re_{hyper}=\frac{U L^{2H-1}}{\nu_{hyper}}
\end{equation}